# Virtual Desktop billing calculation method Amazon / Azure or Google

Tags: virtualization, desktop, vdi

I want to run couple of VMs for charity on Cloud and not sure about billing hence this question.

If I create a Virtual desktop / Workspace on one of cloud provider they say they charge per minute or second.
Does that mean for duration I have connected to it and using it or while its turned on?

If it's everytime I connect to it via workspaces client then it's fine.  That makes sense. If it's while its powered on then once I finish work, I shut the VM down, then reconnect next day. Will it power on automatically or will I have to do it before connecting?

Basically, if we purchase 5 Virtual Desktops.
not all will be used all time, may be 2 or 3 does it mean i will be charged for all when they are powered up but no one conencted?

thanks,
Kaleem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## i got the answer from Amazon by raising a support ticket with them, posting it here incase someone else comes up with same question.

Following are the options available as to workspaces;

AlwaysOn — Use when paying a fixed monthly fee for unlimited usage of your WorkSpaces. This mode is best for users who use their WorkSpace full time as their primary desktop.

AutoStop — Use when paying for your WorkSpaces by the hour. With this mode, your WorkSpaces stop after a specified period of inactivity and the state of apps and data is saved. To set the automatic stop time, use AutoStop Time (hours).

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/running-mode.html

regards,
Kaleem

Comment: You should accept this answer so the question is marked as `Solved` in the system.